# Flutter - how to add list of widgets to column element?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Let's say we have a column. Is it possible to add several widgets using one method? Something like `.addAll()`?

```
Column(
  children: [
    SomeWidget(),
    _someBigWidgetMethod(),
    _severalWidgets(),
  ]
)

_severalWidgets(){
  return [
    Widget(),
    Widget(),
    Widget(),
  ];
}
```

Comment: use the `...` operator `children: [...methodThatReturnsAListOfWidgets()]`, so in your case `children: [
    SomeWidget(),
    _someBigWidgetMethod(),
   ..._severalWidgets(),
  ]
`

Comment: @h8moss can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to add all items in a list into another list, you can use the `...` operator:

```
List<Widget> _myMethod() => [Widget1(), Widget2(), Widget3(), Widget4()];

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      SomeWidget(),
      ..._myMethod(),
    ]
  );
}
```